# Python logger log in double and can log without an handler

Tags: python, python-3.x

When trying to log with Python, sometimes my logger write on both stdout and stderr, despite the fact that only one logger is configured.

This behaviour continue when I remove all the handlers of the logger (see image)

[image]

This is how I instantiate my logger :

```py
_LOGGER_DEFAULT_FORMATTER = logging.Formatter(
    "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
    "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
)

# Create logger & remove previous handlers
logger = logging.getLogger(f"simulation_{str(uuid.uuid4())}")
logger.handlers = []

# Prepare new handlers
stdout_handler: logging.StreamHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)

stdout_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
stdout_handler.setFormatter(_LOGGER_DEFAULT_FORMATTER)
logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)

logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: what does your `logging.DEBUG` file look like?

Comment: what do you mean ? logging.DEBUG is an enumeration built-in in logging module

Comment: I thought you could set up config files like with flasks logger. maybe its because you have both stdout and logger up when you're running your simulation?